# Create a Private App that adds orders to your Shopify Account

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk, shopify-api-node

When i started this day i was sure this will be a very easy task:

1. Create a private app for my client's Shopify Store
2. Create orders for him to see, process fulfil etc...

I'm using nodejs.
Assuming i have all the relevant data to create an order, how can i send an order to my client's Shopify Admin Panel?

Comment: Send an order? Care to elaborate ? An order must include variants ID that should be taken from the store. How are you sending an order... and from where?

Comment: I think i managed to get along. I opened a new Private App from my client's Shopify dashboard -> gave permissions -> got the tokens and passwords -> called the API with orders.json to create a new order.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google instead of Stack Overflow...

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/create-orders

Comment: I think i managed to get along. I opened a new Private App from my client's Shopify dashboard -> gave permissions -> got the tokens and passwords -> called the API with orders.json to create a new order.